# Pandas matplotlib plot Invalid RGBA argument when defining color and style

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

When plotting a line chart with a defined color per line and a defined linestyle per line, using the plot function in a pandas DataFrame an invalid RGBA argument exception is thrown. When one defines either color or linestyle the code works, but it looks like you can't do both at the same time. Further more, this behavior only seems to occur when using one or more `'o'` style lines. How come?

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(1000, 4), index=pd.date_range("1/1/2000", periods=1000), columns=list("ABCD"))
df = df.cumsum()

style = ['-'] * 3 + ['o']

colors = [
    [.6, .6, .6],
    [0, .7, .1],
    [1, .5, .1],
    [0.66, 0.55, 0.84],
]
        
params = dict(
    color=colors,
    style=style,
)

ax = df.plot(**params)
```

Comment: Which version of `pandas` are you using ? You code snippet is working fine with `pandas==1.2.1`, no exception is thrown.

Comment: Hmm I'm running python 3.6.9 on the target machine. The newest version of pandas that runs on this version of python is apparently pandas==1.1.5. So I guess it's time to update python on this machine.

Comment: Indeed, I was able to reproduce the error when using python 3.6.9 with the latest pandas (`1.1.5`). It seems to have been fixed later

Comment: Thanks kind stranger! This will solve our problem. :)